# Quantum gravity without assuming General Relativity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, experimental-physics, quantum-gravity

I understand the discrepancies between *Quantum Field Theory* and *General Relativity*. The mathematical problems involving their unification are quite clear.

Yet there is something that is not fully comprehend-able by me.

We try making a Quantum Theory of Gravity (let's call it QTG) by assuming General Relativity is correct. Why don't we forget GR for a while and then make a QTG only from basic and formal assumptions in QFT just like QED? (I guess we don't assume Maxwell's Equations right from the start in QED, correct me if I am wrong...)

In any case, shouldn't we first try and make a QTG and see if it makes different predictions than that of GR and then experimentally determine which of them is indeed complete (instead of the mainstream "assume GR is correct but incomplete")?

I may be wrong about this formalism, or maybe this has been tried before (A quick google or stack exchange search yeilded null results...), maybe a few of you can guide me towards known results and problems in this approach?

Comment: It is already difficult having the classical limit to find a quantum generalization. Without this, you are in very troubled waters. Anyway, one starts from Maxwell equations, as known classically, and then quantizes them. If you do the same with Einstein equations you just uncover that the theory has too much infinities you cannot dispose of.

Comment: Okay, that works for QED since we know the classical theory. Can't we reverse the argument? Like, assuming the electromagnetic field, quantizing it and then deriving the classical limit i.e. the Maxwell's Equations (pretty much the method of Quantum Chromodynaics) ? I am open to suggestions...

Comment: Take a special-relativistic string (just for the heck of it, I suppose), quantize it, discover gravitons in its spectrum, study low-energy effective behavior. Isn't it like smth you suggest?

Comment: Feynman's book on general relativity does take that approach, constructing a quantum gravity just from general properties of gravity as a quantum field theory. It's an interesting book although it's an obsolete theory of quantum gravity.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Almost... almost exactly what I am thinking of, but we might have a little dispute over the "string" landscape. The "string" kind of creates a strange observer independent length scale (else we might have shrinking strings, thus more energy and voila! just by accelerating your reference frame, you convert an electron to a proton. Not a very elegant idea... ) . If we keep that string part aside, isn't what you suggest possible?

Comment: @Slereah And why is it obsolete?

Comment: It uses covariant quantum gravity, which was shown to be non-renormalizable.

Comment: Isn't LQG also a covariant theory?